# How to fix index out of bounds exception on string split in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String parts[] = formattedString.split("\\:");
String partA = parts[0];
String partB = parts[1];
```

I'm trying to split a string before and after the ":" symbol.
For example, "Before:After" works, but in the case where there is nothing after the ":" like "Before: " gives me an exception. I've tried to check for `null` in `parts[1]` but it still throws exception.

Comment: Check the length of the resulting array.

Comment: The problem here is unrelated to regex. It's that you don't understand arrays. I'm also betting you haven't thought about strings like `"Beginning:Middle:End"`, either.

Comment: If you know there's a possibility of that don't assume there's going to be something at index 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot! It helped.

Comment: The problem is that you need to read the Javadoc of [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))... call `formattedString.split("\\:", -1);` instead.

Comment: the String you are splitting for (`"\\:"`) looks pretty much like the separator between drive letter and path on windows systems.

So why don't go with this to get the drive letter:

 `File theFile= new File(formattedString);
    if(theFile.isAbsolute()) 
          String driveLetter=file.getPath().getRoot();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the array to determine whether **anything** at index 1 exists before referencing it.

```
if(parts.length > 1) {
    //do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of the array that the split method gives is determined by the number of elements that could be splitted.

This means that if you don't have a second element, the length of the array will be 1 instead of 2.

You should check the length of the array to determine if there is a second element.

Answer (score 1):

```
String parts[] = formattedString.split("\\:");
String partA = parts[0];
String partB = parts[1];
```

Into above code you want to access index 0 and 1 so please check first the array parts have these index or not. before accessing these index please check the length of array.